# undefined method: nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, undefined

Can someone help explain why the following code produces a:

```
5.times do 
  star_count = star_count + 1
  puts "*" * star_count
end

#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

The desired effect of the code is the following image below:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Sorry for including the asterisk triangle as code ... was not outputting right so that was the only solution I could think of. Treating the triangle as an image did not work either.

Comment: Thanks Eric. So if you don't initialize a variable before referencing that variable in the loop, Ruby will always give a nil:NilClass error?

Comment: Well, in this case yes. The variable is dynamically declared, but it's value is `nil` here. So calling `+` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start_count` must be initialized to `0` before the loop in this case.

Anyway, there is more idiomatic in Ruby:

```
5.times do |index|
  puts '*' * (index + 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `upto` instead of `times` to start from another index than zero.

```
1.upto(5) do |index|
  puts '*' * index
end
```